# User function default argument one of c(...)

Tags: r, function, default

I'm trying to set a default for a function I've written to calculate either the distance between plants to be set or the number of seedlings per hectare at a set spacing - however the argument  for the type of planting system can take one of several inputs, and will change what the function does accordingly. I'd like system to be set to "square" if system is missing. This is what I've tried so far.

```
plant_spacing <- function(distance, distance_a, distance_b, system=c("square","rectangular"), stems_per_ha, area_m2=10000, output=c("stems per ha","spacing")){

  if(missing(system)){
    system=="square"
  }

  if(output=="stems per ha" & system=="rectangular"){
    area_m2/(dist_a*dist_b)
  }

  if(output=="stems per ha" & system=="square"){
    area_m2/(distance^2)
  }

  if(output=="spacing" & system=="square"){
    sqrt(area_m2/stems_per_ha)
  }
}
```

It does the right thing, but throws a load of warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (output == "stems per ha" & system == "rectangular") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (output == "stems per ha" & system == "square") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (output == "spacing" & system == "square") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Every `if` statement in R must have a single logical value, but your comparisons result in length 2 logical vectors.

```
system=c("square","rectangular")
output=c("stems per ha","spacing")
output=="stems per ha" & system=="rectangular"
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Instead, just define the default in the function. And then the user can change the value if necessary.

```
plant_spacing <- function(distance, 
                          distance_a, 
                          distance_b, 
                          system="square", 
                          stems_per_ha,
                          area_m2=10000, 
                          output="stems per ha"){

  return(c(system,output))
}
plant_spacing()
[1] "square"       "stems per ha"
plant_spacing(system = "rectangular")
[1] "rectangular"  "stems per ha"
```